# CSS transition doesn't work from bottom to top

Tags: css, css-transitions

i used below `css` for my sidebar and `transition` works since this sidebar opens from left to right

**CSS**

```
.sidebar{
    position: absolute;
    width: 300px;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #FFF;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 101;
    left: -310px;
    -webkit-transition: all 500ms cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.610, 0.355, 1.000); 
    -moz-transition: all 500ms cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.610, 0.355, 1.000); 
    -o-transition: all 500ms cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.610, 0.355, 1.000); 
    transition: all 500ms cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.610, 0.355, 1.000); /* easeOutCubic */
}
```

and here am trying to `transition` from bottom to top with the same css code but there is no transition effect for below code.

```
.sidebarr{
    position: fixed;
    font-size: 15px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #FFF;
    height: 70%;
    z-index: 101;
    bottom: -100%;
    transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.000, 0.000, 0.230, 1);
}

.sidebarr.opened{
top: 30%
}
```

Now how do i animate when div slides from bottom to top.

Comment: Surely the `.opened` property should be `bottom: 0` not `top: 30%`? I would suggest making a working example in a snippet so show the problem in action.

Comment: you should use animated.css. It is easy and nice to use

Comment: @DBS yes it works, i didn't notice this simple solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace

```
.sidebarr.opened{
top: 30%
}
```

with

```
.sidebarr.opened{
    bottom: 0
    }
```